Conformal Map f from Sector to Unit Disk with $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = \frac{1}{2}$
The following is a question from an old complex analysis qualifying exam:
(a) Find a function f that conformally maps the region $\{z: |argz|<1\}$ one-to-one onto the region $\{w: |w| < 1\}$. Show that the function you have found satisfies the required conditions.
(b) Is it possible to require that $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = \frac{1}{2}$? If yes, give an explicit map; if no, explain why not.
The provided solution for part (a) constructs the map $f(z) = \frac{z^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-1}{z^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+1}$ which conformally maps $\{z: |argz|<1\}$ onto $\{w: |w| < 1\}$ with $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = \frac{2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-1}{2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+1}$.
The provided solution for part (b) is the following:
Suppose $\tilde{f}(z)$ is an arbitrary conformal map of $\{z: |argz|<1\}$ onto $\{w: |w| < 1\}$ with $\tilde{f}(1)=0.$ Then $f \circ \tilde{f}^{-1}$ is a conformal map of $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{D}$ with $\left(f \circ \tilde{f}^{-1}\right)(0) = 0.$ Also, $\tilde{f} \circ f^{-1}$ is a conformal map of $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{D}$ with $\left(\tilde{f} \circ f^{-1}\right)(0) = 0.$ By Schwarz Lemma, we have both $\left|\left(f \circ \tilde{f}^{-1}\right)\right| \leq |z|$ and $\left|\left(\tilde{f} \circ f^{-1}\right)\right| \leq |z|,$ which implies that $|f(z)| = |\tilde{f}(z)|$ for every $z \in \{z: |argz|<1\}.$ Since, $f(2) = \frac{2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-1}{2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+1}$, we cannot require that $\tilde{f}(2) = \frac{1}{2}$.
How are we able to deduce, from having both $\left|\left(f \circ \tilde{f}^{-1}\right)\right| \leq |z|$ and $\left|\left(\tilde{f} \circ f^{-1}\right)\right| \leq |z|$, that $|f(z)| = |\tilde{f}(z)|$ for every $z \in \{z: |argz|<1\}$?

Since $f,\tilde{f}:\{z: |\arg z|<1\} \to \mathbb{D}$  are assumed to be bijections, we know that for every $z \in\{z: |\arg z|<1\} $ there are $w, \tilde{w} \in \mathbb{D}$ so that $f(z)=w$ and $\tilde{f}(z)=\tilde{w}$.
Since $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ are both assumed to satisfy the hypotheses of the  Schwarz Lemma, for every $z \in\{z: |\arg z|<1\} $ we have
$$\left|f(z)\right|=\left|\left(f \circ \tilde{f}^{-1} \circ \tilde{f}\right)(z)\right|=\left|\left(f \circ \tilde{f}^{-1}\right)(\tilde{w})\right| \leq |\tilde{w}|=\left|\tilde{f}(z)\right|$$
and
$$\left|\tilde{f}(z)\right|=\left|\left(\tilde{f} \circ f^{-1} \circ f\right)(z)\right|=\left|\left(\tilde{f} \circ f^{-1}\right)(w)\right| \leq |w|=\left| f(z)\right|.$$
